# Getting the second nearest [x,y] point using KNN algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to find the nearest points on an x,y plane within given radius using kd trees. I mapped all the points in the tree, but the problem arise since the points I am providing to the algorithm to search for the nearest point are themself mapped in the tree. In other words, I'm getting the same point in return so the distance is basically 0. So I should be looking for the second nearest point I guess. The way I thought it might be achievable was doing the same thing but getting the result that was worst than the best_result but better than the root. I have been trying to implement this but have been unsuccessful so far. I did this with nested for loops its way easier with for loops to get the second-best result.

here's my kd tree implementation:

```
def kdtree(points, depth = 0 ):
    n = len(points)
    if n<=0:
        return None
    axis = depth % k
    sorted_points = sorted(points, key = lambda point: point[axis])
    
    if n % 2 == 0:
        median_idx = int(n/2)
    else:
        median_idx = floor(n/2)
    return{
        'point': sorted_points[median_idx],
        'left': kdtree(sorted_points[:median_idx], depth+1),
        'right': kdtree(sorted_points[median_idx+1:], depth+1)
    }
```

Here is my function for searching the nearest point

```
kd_nearest_search (root, point, depth = 0):
    if root is None:
            return None
        axis = depth % k
        apposite_branch = None
    
        if point[axis] < root['point'][axis]:
            next_branch = root['left']
            opposite_branch = root['right']
        else:
            next_branch = root['right']
        opposite_branch = root['left']
    
    best_result = best_distance(point,kdtree_closest_point(next_branch,point,depth+1), root['point'])


    if distance(point,best_result) > (abs(point[axis] - root['point'][axis])):
        best_result = best_distance(point,kdtree_closest_point(next_branch,point,depth+1), best_result)
    
    
    return best_result
```

Comment: My intuition is that you can't make a choice to go down one side or another of a splitting plane and be sure that the closest point doesn't lie on the other side. You probably need to store bounding boxes or bounding circles at each node of all the points in the sub trees, and use them to work out if the closest point could possibly be in there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your kd implementation.  But I'll give you the basic idea.

Create tuples of `(min_possible_distance, type, object)` where the distance is the minimum possible distance to your searched for point the type can be either `"box"` or `"point"`, and the object is whatever the thing is.

Put those tuples into a [heap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html).

And now, in pseudocode, you do this:

```
place (0, "box", root_of_tree) into new heap
while heap is not empty:
    (distance, type, obj) = pop minimal element from heap.
    if type == "point":
        yield obj
    else:
       if obj has a point:
           store (distance, "point", point) in heap
       for child_box from obj:
           store (min_distance", "box", child_box) in heap
```

This will yield points in the kd tree, from closest to farthest.  So you can just search until you find the second one.  But alternately you could ask for the 10 nearest and it would give you that instead.

Comment: I need to keep the complexity below n^2.

Comment: @zayant21 Then you're in luck.  Each nearest neighbor lookup is polynomial in `log(n)`.